# Django: After logging out if i press the back button will go back to the web page

Tags: django, python-3.x

here is my logout view since its redirecting to my home page, after clicking on the browser's back button will generate the page that was visited before.
How can i prevent that from happening?

```
def logout_page(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, msg_from_db('goodbye'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: Yea that would be cache, if you refresh that page or click any links on the page, it would be logged out.

Comment: yeah it gives me 500 nothing works but i don't want it to be accessible

Comment: You are actually logged out, Its just browser cache that loads that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use login_required decorator for your protected views

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
   # your code
```